# Why does the right side of the header go of screen when width is set to 100% and left side doesnt even reach the edge of the screen?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have the header go from one side of the screen to the other and stop just like how the left side does, however it extends much pass and goes off the screen. Also I thought that when you set a specific width that meas that it starts from the edge o the screen and stops at the other edge of the screen.

```
body{
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
}

header{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #0000CD;

}

nav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;


}

ul.main-menu{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-around;
    list-style: none;
}

li.menu-item{



}




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Why OneDrive?</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/styles.css">
    <script src="../JS/3picslideshow.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul class="main-menu">
                <li class="menu-item">Home</li>
                <li class="menu-item">Usage</li>
                <li class="menu-item">About</li>
                <li class="menu-item">Acknowledgments</li>
            </ul> 
        </nav>
    </header>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the width: 100%; from the body class. You don't need it. That will fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The `body` element has a margin by default. Remove that by adding

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

.. and a 100% wide element will perfectly fit the width. Example:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.x {
  width: 100%;
  background: #fa0;
}
```

```html
<div class="x">The DIV with class "x"</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `width: 100%` from your `body` tag.
It seems to work.

Example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7jcqsjw6/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the margin from the body.